# Hypothesis regarding annuity loan and recursive annuity loans

Tags: finance, geometric-series

I have a question regarding an annuity loan calculation and I would like to prove whether the hypothesis I am stating is correct:

Consider an annuity loan $L_{1}$, with a principal of $T_{1}$ and an interest rate of $i_{1} = (5.5\% /12)$ per month and a duration of $D_{1}=1$. The annuity would be $J_{1} = \frac{i}{1-(1+i)^{-n}} \cdot T \approx 85.84$.

If the borrower is unable to pay $J_{1,1}$, but the borrower can pay $Lim<J_{1}$ per month, then the lender is willing to provide an additional loan $L_{2}$ to cover the difference, with a principal of $J_{1}-Lim$ against the same interest rate $i_{1}$ and for $D_{1}$. For the second month, a new loan is created $L_{3}$ to cover the difference of the second month and so on. In addition in the newly created loans, when the borrower in that month cannot pay the loan back, again a new loan is created for that loan used to previously cover the difference in $Lim$ and $J$. This goes on until the loan is repaid.

Hypothesis: I hypothesize that the "recursive loan coverage" process (first case) is actually equal to the $L_{1}$ with only a longer duration and $J=Lim$ (second case) and therefore give the lender the same returns (i.e. **the total amount of interest paid** in the first case is the same as the second case).

Since this is a toy example in my head, I haven't been able to prove this hypothesis yet. But I wonder whether someone can give me insights on how to deal with the recursive loan coverage process. I can imagine that this might not be the same, but then I am wondering whether there is a solution/formula to show this difference.

Comment: Note that all loans are annuity loans in this example.